# offsetTop and static or absolute positioned

Tags: css

In HTML I have a div which is relative positioned. It has a border of 6px. It has no padding. In it is another div. This div has no margin.

I look at it in Firefox.

I have made a fiddle, [jsfiddle.net/ericjvandervelden/uKgYs/10](http://jsfiddle.net/ericjvandervelden/uKgYs/10) .

If the inner div is static, it has `offsetTop=0` I understand. 
But if the inner div is absolute positioned, it has `offsetTop= -6px`. I do not understand this.

Comment: Some more HTML and the relevant CSS would be useful; it's hard to know if it's because of a problem with the markup, an issue with the CSS or a combination of the two.

Comment: Hello, I have made a fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/ericjvandervelden/uKgYs/10/ . So if .in is static, it's offsetTop equals 0 and if .in is absolute positioned, it's offsetTop equals -6px , the width of .out's border. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Firefox implementation of offSetTop might be buggy with absolute positioning.

I've improved [your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uKgYs/16/).

I've tested the function and jquery implementation of position and offset in firefox, chrome and IE8 and well, no results are the same...

```
Absolute
        |  offSetTop   |  jquery.offSet.top | jquery.position.top
Firefox |  -6          |  30                | 0
Chrome  |  0           |  26                | 0
IE8     |  5           |  25                | -1

Static
        |  offSetTop   |  jquery.offSet.top | jquery.position.top
Firefox |  0           |  384                | 0
Chrome  |  0           |  376                | 0
IE8     |  5           |  371                | -1
```

My recommandation would be to use jquery.position instead of the native offSetTop if you use absolute positions.

Although, IE still act strangely. At least, it act strangely no matter the type of position.

I believe this [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=492551) might be of interest.